# C# - Partial Search in Hashtables

Tags: c#, hashtable

Can we check for a part of string in hashtable key? For example, our key is

```
key = cardnumber +","+ tokennumber
```

Eg, key would be then

```
key = 1234,7463
```

I know have a function called `containskey()` but do we have something that could partially check for a string in a hashtable key?

For example, if we could search

```
if(key.contains(tokennumber))
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. It's a bad idea.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have  data in two  .csv files which I have to store and compare. The issue with the data is that they don't have a single unique key that link each other. For some records there is emp Id that is matching and for some it is the tokennumber that is matching.

Comment: The please show us the CSB file and then we can suggest a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it but the lookup won't be as fast.

You can cast the `Keys` Collection to of type string and then perform basic Linq on it to get the Keys that you want.

Example:

```
var listOfKeys = hashTable.Keys.Cast<string>().Where(x => x.Contains(tokennumber)).ToList();
```

after this, you can loop over the Keys and perform the operation that you want.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad idea: you waste an advantage of Hashtables (btw, don't use class `Hashtable`, use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead) and key lookup complexity becomes `O(n)` vs `O(1)` in nomral key retrieving.

If your tokens are unique, consider incapsulating your key data in some class and provide `IEqulityComparer` to dictionary. For example:

```
public class KeyData
{ 
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }

    public string TokenNumber { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"{CardNumber},{TokenNumber}";
}

public class KeyDataTokenComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyData>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyData x, KeyData y) => x?.TokenNumber == y?.TokenNumber;

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] KeyData obj) => obj.TokenNumber.GetHashCode();
}

// usage:
var dict = new Dictionary<KeyData, SomeClass>(new KeyDataTokenComparer());
// filling dict
if (dict.ContainsKey(new() { TokenNumber = "token_to_search" }))
{ }
```

Another approach (especially if your tokens aren't unique and/or if you need to fast lookup card number after a token number) – to use composite dictionary class. For example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, SomeClass>>();
```

The key here is your token number, value – a dictionary where the key is card number and the value - is your original value.

Comment: "key lookup complexity becomes O(n) vs O(1)" - what do you mean here? Both hash tables and dictionaries are `O(1)`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I didn’t say Hashtable class has O(n) key retrieving, it’s O(1) ofc. I just noticed that partial key searching (in any hash-based collection) will lead us to O(n).

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I'd suggest removing the bracketed comment and make it its own sentence to avoid confusion.