# Partial search in Dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a scenario where I have a dictionary A where key is stored as -
`'employeeId,cardnumber'`

```
    key                         value
'Id47835,12345', 'Emma,9843675867,Park Street'
'Id47800,4444',  'Sam,981275337,New Street'
'Id47866,41234', 'Pam,9812123337,Old Street'
'Id47866,03434', 'Jim,9866623337,Old Street'
'ID95455,22345', 'Robert,984735846,New Street'
```

EmployeeIds and Card numbers are unique.

I have to compare some values with the above dictionary. I will be reading those values from a .csv file. The comparison conditions are as follows.

CSV file:

```
EmpID     CardNumber  Name  Phone       Address
Id47835   12345       Emma  9843675867  Park Street ---- this user is present in dict A - same emp Id and same card number

Id47800   8888        Sam   981275337   New Street ----- this user is present in dict A - same emp Id and different card number

Id33333   41234       Pam   9812123337  Old Street ----- this user is present in dict A - different emp Id and same card number

ID94899   3434        Jim   9812123337  Old Street ----  this user is not present in dict A - different emp Id and different card number - leading zeroes are considered different.
```

Currently, I am doing the following from:

[Check if any part of a hashtable value contains certain string c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736468/check-if-any-part-of-a-hashtable-value-contains-certain-string-c-sharp)

[C# - Partial Search in Hashtables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884319/c-sharp-partial-search-in-hashtables)

```
if (dictA.Keys.Cast<string>().Any(k => k.Contains(employeeID) || k.Contains(cardnumber)))
//then do something
```

With this approach I am able to check all the 3 conditions mentioned above, but my last condition is failing (leading zeroes)

When I compare card number 3434 with 03434, it yields as true. Of course, because I am using `contains` and 03434 contains 3434.

Is their any alternative to partial search dictionaries?

**UPDATE**
Here are the .csv files.

File 1 - Dictionary is built on this

```
Name,PhoneNumber,AccessDetails,Address
Emma,987462534,ID47835|12345,Park Street
Sam,975323444,ID47800|4444,New Street
Jim,908796856,ID47866|41234,Old Street
Pam,985764567,ID94899|03434,Old Street
Robert,984735846,ID95455|22345,New Street
```

File 2

```
Name,PhoneNumber,AccessDetails,Address
Emma,987462534,ID47835|12345,Park Street
Sam,975323444,ID47800|8888,New Street
Jim,908796856,ID33333|41234,Old Street
Pam,985764567,ID94899|3434,Old Street
```

Access Details are as `employeeId|Card Number`.
Apart from the other mentioned conditions...if there is a user whose emp id and card number does not match then there are other scenario for him.

Comment: It's a complete waste to have a dictionary like that. They exist to quickly look up the value based on the whole key.

Comment: What you have is not really a unique key, so use something like `List` instead, why use `Dictionary`?

Comment: So you want to find an employee by knowing only the `EmployeeID` or the `CardNumber`, but not both? And also you want the search for the `CardNumber` to be non-sensitive to leading zeros?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, the scenario is that if both .csv file's cardnumber and emp id , or if either emp id or cardnumber match with the dictionary( which is another .csv file that I am storing in a dictionary), then do something else if both empid and cardnumber don't match match with the dictionary then do something. yes, card number 01234 and 1234 are different.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias It's basically .csv files that I have to read and process the data and output results. So, currently I am storing the data in dictionaries. Earlier I was using hashtables but people on stackoverflow suggested I should use dictionary so I switched to dictionary and now they are saying dictionary is also bad.

Comment: Anonymous both the `HashSet<T>` and the `Dictionary<K,V>` are good collections, when you use them correctly. For the dictionary this means to search by the key: `dict.TryGetValue(key, out value)`. This way you get O(1) performance, because the key is searched in one of the buckets that the dictionary contains internally, and each bucket contains one key on average. If you enumerate all the dictionary to find the entry that you want, the performance is `O(N)`. Which is the same with a `List<T>`, and all the internal bucket-related machinery of the dictionary goes for nothing.

Comment: Is it possible, even theoretically, that there are two employees with the same ID, or the same card number?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias these two are different files...and within the same file id and cardnumber are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably more efficient solutions but your problem can be solved by doing the following:

```
if (dictA.Keys.Cast<string>().Any(k => {
    var parts = k.Split(',');
    return parts[0] == employeeID || parts[1] == cardnumber
}))
```

It would be much better to preprocess the data than have to perform the split and compare on it for each search though. The solution assumes that the key will always be in the format '{id},{cardNumber}' with no blanks, trailing spaces, etc.

Comment: I agree that this is the best solution for a horrible data structure. I'd love to know why the OP thinks he has to start with a dictionary.

Comment: @Enigmativity How else should I store the entire .csv files? I have two .csv files and I have to compare the data and then print the output in another .csv.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this answer I gave to a similar question. Basically process each row of the CSV into whatever datamodel you want then do the operations on that before outputting back as a CSV. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74890280/8532748

Comment: Please show us the unadulterated CSV files.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have already shared my .csv in the question. I have two .csv files that I have to process and compare and print output to another .csv. I have stored the first .csv in the dictionary that I have showed above. Both .csv files are in the same format.

Comment: @Anonymous - You have called something a CSV file, but it isn't one. Please post the actual unadulterated CSV file. Also, I'm suggesting that you don't use a dictionary, so please post the CSV file that the dictionary is currently built from.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have updated my question and added the .csv files.

Answer (score -1):

You really what to do something like this:

```
var file1 =
    File
        .ReadLines(@"file1.csv")
        .Select(x => x.Split(','))
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(xs => new
        {
            Name = xs[0],
            PhoneNumber = xs[1],
            EmpID = xs[2].Split('|')[0],
            CardNo = xs[2].Split('|')[1],
            Address = xs[3],
        })
        .ToArray();

var file2 =
    File
        .ReadLines(@"file2.csv")
        .Select(x => x.Split(','))
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(xs => new
        {
            Name = xs[0],
            PhoneNumber = xs[1],
            EmpID = xs[2].Split('|')[0],
            CardNo = xs[2].Split('|')[1],
            Address = xs[3],
        })
        .ToArray();

var query =
    from f1 in file1
    from f2 in file2
    where f1.EmpID == f2.EmpID || f1.CardNo == f2.CardNo
    select f2;
```